# Why would Donald Trump be arrested?

Tags: criminal-law, new-york-state, arrest, indictment

The New York Times [writes:](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/04/03/us/donald-trump-indicted-new-york.html)

> Donald J. Trump is preparing to walk into a Manhattan courtroom as both a defendant and a candidate, making final plans for his **arrest** on Tuesday [...].

Why would he be arrested? Is there a danger of flight? That seems implausible, given that he has arranged his appearance in front of the court out of his own volition, and because of his commercial, family and real estate ties to the country, and his plans to run for president again.

Is there a danger of destroying evidence? In all reality, that would have happened by now, and most relevant searches have probably been conducted already.

What other reasons would be there for an arrest?

**As a clarification:** If I'm not mistaken, in Germany an indictment would simply be delivered by special registered mail, unless one of the above-mentioned dangers was present.

In the U.S., a simple delivery of an indictment can take on an appearance which I can only perceive as unnecessarily disparaging. A defendant is presumed innocent unless proven guilty. To me this principle implies that defendants should be treated with respect like any other citizen. Putting them in humiliating situations, let alone using force like restraining them with handcuffs like in the [case of Mr. Weisselberg](https://www.msnbc.com/the-beat-with-ari/watch/trump-org-cfo-allen-weisselberg-waives-right-to-remain-silent-during-arrest-117095493824) contradicts this principle, unless there is reason to believe they would flee or otherwise obstruct the trial.

Comment: To clarify, Trump isn't being "arrested" in the sense of being pulled out of his house, thrown in a paddywagon and driven to jail. This "arrest" will likely consist of nothing more than him showing up at the court, receiving his warrant, being entered into a criminal-justice database, and then sitting in a room waiting for the judge to call his case. You may get better answers if you elaborate on your question: Is there a specific part of that process that seems unjustifiable here?

Comment: Different legal systems may value different things in different priorities, and several common law systems take public appearance before a judge as well as the right to confront your accusers quite seriously (for better or worse). On the other hand, several civil law systems protects the privacy interests of the accused and other participants (incl. victims) of the justice system, but prosecutors can issue penal orders without approval from a judge and the convicted is burdened with procedural costs when deciding whether to pursue judicial recourses.

Comment: The DA specifically said that he would *not* be handcuffed. But he'll be fingerprinted and a DNA sample taken. That's hard to do with registered mail.

Comment: @Barmar It is also entirely unnecessary. It is also still an arrest, handcuffs or not.

Comment: I think they may be trying to make a point of treating him like any other "perp" -- the whole "no one is above the law" thing.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "out of his own volition"? It's not like he's the one who asked to appear in front of the court. Do you perhaps mean "has not needed to be dragged kicking and screaming to the courthouse"? I'm not trying to ridicule here, it's a genuine question asking you to consider/explain what in particular Donald Trump has done differently compared to other people who are indicted.

Comment: @Flater I tried to find a wording that means "he could have chosen not to". Many people with arrest warrants choose to not show up in court (typically because they cannot pay a fine and don't want to go to prison because they have children and need to go to work). Because he could have chosen to behave differently I called it "his own volition". "Voluntarily" seemed wrong (it was a court/jury order, after all). What I tried to say was "he didn't try to evade" the court (and gave no indication he'd do so before the warrant was issued).

Comment: @Flater Oh, and what's different to the average Joe is mainly that his whereabouts and place of residence are well-known. It would not be a problem at all to deliver a registered letter, for example, possibly to one of his legal representatives. That's a big difference to a defendant whose address may be unknown or inaccurate or who must be feared to flee.

Comment: Apparently he was given the option to be arraigned remotely via Zoom. He did not choose that option. I presume because the spectacle of going to the courthouse would help him politically.

Comment: @jwenting Privacy is the least concern in a public arraignment.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Although conversely, the judge prohibited live broadcast of the arraignment.

Answer (score 35):

An accused would be arrested for the purposes of [***arraignment***](https://nycourts.gov/courthelp/criminal/arraignments.shtml) ("even a scheduled arrest is still an arrest"). That does not entail that the accused would be held in custody pending or during trial. Many commenters are of the view that Mr. Trump would be released under his own recognizance without bail.

Reference: [AP News](https://apnews.com/article/trump-arrest-process-what-to-know-02a2ce34e03e25ab2fdd0e81dbcc62c7).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145088/discussion-on-answer-by-jen-why-would-donald-trump-be-arrested); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 19):

New York Criminal Procedure Law, [section 210.10](https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/laws/CPL/210.10), *Requirement of and methods of securing defendant's appearance for arraignment upon indictment,* subsection 3 (emphasis added):

> 3. If the defendant has not previously been held by a local criminal
>    court for the action of the grand jury and the filing of the indictment
>    constituted the commencement of the criminal action, **the superior court**
>    must order the indictment to be filed as a sealed instrument until the
>    defendant is produced or appears for arraignment, and **must issue a
>    superior court warrant of arrest. Upon the request of the district
>    attorney, in lieu of a superior court warrant of arrest, the court may
>    issue a summons if it is satisfied that the defendant will respond
>    thereto. Upon the request of the district attorney, in lieu of a warrant
>    of arrest or summons, the court may instead authorize the district
>    attorney to direct the defendant to appear for arraignment on a
>    designated date if it is satisfied that the defendant will so appear.** A
>    superior court warrant of arrest is executable anywhere in the state.
>    Such warrant may be addressed to any police officer whose geographical
>    area of employment embraces either the place where the offense charged
>    was allegedly committed or the locality of the court by which the
>    warrant is issued. It must be executed in the same manner as an
>    ordinary warrant of arrest, as provided in section 120.80, and following
>    the arrest the executing police officer must without unnecessary delay
>    perform all recording, fingerprinting, photographing and other
>    preliminary police duties required in the particular case, and bring the
>    defendant before the superior court. If such superior court is not
>    available, the executing police officer may bring the defendant to the
>    local correctional facility of the county in which such superior court
>    sits, to be detained there until not later than the commencement of the
>    next session of such court occurring on the next business day.

So, the district attorney can ask the court not to issue a warrant, but the court isn't obliged to comply.  In fact the court is obliged not to comply if it concludes that the defendant may not appear voluntarily or in response to a summons.

My guess is that the district attorney did not make the necessary request.  However, as noted in the AP article linked in Jen's answer, "Manhattan District Attorney Alvin Bragg’s office said it had contacted Trump’s lawyer to coordinate his surrender and arraignment," so it's entirely possible that the third option *is* in play, in which case Trump won't necessarily be arrested.

Comment: IIUC, a summons would not lead to an arrest? Because Trump gave no indication that he would evade the court, the question is perhaps just why the district attorney didn't choose the mildest legal instrument available.

Comment: All the reports said that he would be fingerprinted and a DNA sample taken, and there has been speculation about a mug shot. Is that independent of the arrest?

Comment: @barmar Apparently, no mug shot for fears of it leaking, which would expose the department to legal and publicity risks. Also, allegedly the Manhattan Criminal Courts Building is not equipped to take mug shots, although in all reality this is likely a pretext. But there is no shortage of images of Trump, so mug shots would not be needed for identification or a manhunt.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yeah, Colbert last night speculated on which of his many famous poor pictures would be best to use. He settled on a shot of him playing tennis that showed off his bug butt.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica the options are warrant, summons, or just making an appointment.  I believe you're right that only the first implies arrest (at least before the arraignment; there would have to be an arrest at some point if there's a conviction, but I don't know when that would be).  I don't know what option is actually in play.  The press using the word "arrest" doesn't imply that they know, either; they could also be making assumptions since s warrant is the default course of action.

Comment: It is not beyond the bounds of possibility that Trump was happy to be arrested and made non-arrest a non-option purely to create political theater.  These kind of machinations happen with politicians and celebrities all the time, not just in the US but worldwide.